# Lambda Expression LINQ Equivalent to SQL Exists Query on Same Table/Variable

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am attempting to replicate the following SQL query in LINQ using the lambda expression format (to keep it consistent with the code developed so far):

```
SELECT *
FROM Product p
WHERE p.DateObsolete IS NULL
    OR p.DateObsolete > GETDATE()
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM dbo.Product p1
        WHERE p1.Ref01 = p.Ref01
            AND p1.Ref02 = p.Ref02
            AND p1.Ref03 = p.Ref03
            AND p1.Version = p.Version + 1
            AND p1.DateApproved IS NULL
        )
```

Having looked at other questions ([Linq subquery same table using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679641/linq-subquery-same-table-using-lambda) was the closest I could find but but didn't show how to "or" conditions) on SO and elsewhere I thought the following would work but it just causes a stack overflow (seriously) exception and a message about a pdb file not being loaded, which I think is a bit of a red herring.

```
products = products
        .Where(p => !p.DateObsolete.HasValue 
              || p.DateObsolete > DateTime.Now 
              || products.Any(p1 => p1.Ref01 == p.Ref01 
                         && p1.Ref02 == p.Ref02 
                         && p1.Ref03 == p.Ref03 
                         && p1.Version == p.Version + 1 
                         && p1.DateApproved == null));
```

products is an IQueryable variable.

Product is defined in this context as DbSet of:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Ref01 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Ref02 { get; set; }

    public int Ref03 { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateReceivedByGraphics { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateObsolete { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool Discontinued { get; set; }

}
```

As you may gather I'm new to LINQ (and to posting questions on SO) so any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Can we see the Product entity? I mean all the properties implied in this query.

Comment: Missing information: EF version + type and origin of `products `. Database is Sql Server I guess.

Comment: Try assign your expression to a new variable, like `var newProducts = products.Where(.....`

Comment: Wasn't completely sure if you meant the whole class or not so thought I'd post it. I believe this is EF version 4.3.0 and it is SQL Server.

Comment: Most likely it's related to `products` variable closure. Try `var query = products.Where(...)` instead of assigning the resulting query to the `products` variable.

Comment: Thanks but the same error occurs when I assign the query results to a different variable.

Comment: Please provide a minimal but full code reproducing the issue (a.k.a. [mcve]).

Comment: Sorry, @AleksAndreev and Ivan, I had another go at re-assignment (I was trying to trace the exact point of failure) and it's worked: I'm not sure what I did differently though.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to you both! Not sure how I record this as the answer though, as they're both in comments?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this with a Join.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today; // or .Now
var products = context.Products.Join(context.Products,
    p1 => new { p1.Ref01, p1.Ref02, p1.Ref03 },
    p2 => new { p2.Ref01, p2.Ref02, p2.Ref03 },
    (p1, p2) => new { Product = p1, p1.Version, JoinedVersion = p2.Version, JoinedDateApproved = p2.DateApproved } )
    .Where(x=> x.Product.DateObsolete > date && x.JoinedVersion == x.Version+1 && !x.JoinedDateApproved.HasValue)
    .Select(x=>x.Product)
    .ToList();
```

This joins Product to itself on Ref 1-3, but then selects the "left" side project, along with it's version, the "right" side's version and date approved. The Where condition isolates cases where the "right" version is 1 greater than the left and has no date approved. The result will be the "left" products that have counterparts that match those criteria.

Update:
If you have already filtered the products down to a known set of applicable products, then this will work against Objects. For example:

```
// given products is an IQueryable representing the filtered products...
DateTime date = DateTime.Today; // or .Now

var productList = products.ToList(); // Materialize the EF Queryable into list of entities.

    productList = productList.Join(productList,
        p1 => new { p1.Ref01, p1.Ref02, p1.Ref03 },
        p2 => new { p2.Ref01, p2.Ref02, p2.Ref03 },
        (p1, p2) => new { Product = p1, p1.Version, JoinedVersion = p2.Version, JoinedDateApproved = p2.DateApproved } )
        .Where(x=> x.Product.DateObsolete > date && x.JoinedVersion == x.Version+1 && !x.JoinedDateApproved.HasValue)
        .Select(x=>x.Product)
        .ToList();
```

If your goal is to try and keep this as an IQueryable scoped to EF then I'd suspect that if it's possible, it might not be worth the complexity/time. Worst-case if you did want to preserve the IQueryable, use the above to select Product IDs into a list, then apply that list as a filter against the IQueryable.

```
var productList = products.ToList(); // Materialize the EF Queryable into list of entities.

// Fetch a list of applicable product IDs.
var productIds = productList.Join(productList,
    p1 => new { p1.Ref01, p1.Ref02, p1.Ref03 },
    p2 => new { p2.Ref01, p2.Ref02, p2.Ref03 },
    (p1, p2) => new { ProductId = p1.ProductId, DateObsolete = p1.DateObsolete, p1.Version, JoinedVersion = p2.Version, JoinedDateApproved = p2.DateApproved } )
    .Where(x=> x.DateObsolete > date && x.JoinedVersion == x.Version+1 && !x.JoinedDateApproved.HasValue)
    .Select(x=>x.ProductId)
    .ToList();

// Filter the original IQueryable.
products = products.Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.ProductId));
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I can do it this way. Some more background: this query is one of several run on the original products collection to identify the collection of products that meet user-specified search criteria so I need to run it against the collection in the products variable rather than the original data set. I tried this and it didn't seem that the join could be started with the variable. Sorry if this is just exposing my lack of understanding of LINQ!

Answer (score 0):

It was as Aleks Andreev and Ivan Stoev suggested that assigning the expression to a new variable sorted out the problem. I'm not sure why this didn't work the first time but my guess is that, after completing the query I tried to re-assign the result back to the original variable - in order not to have to change the variable name in all the code that followed my change.